# DataTrigger in ControlTemplate does not work

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, datatemplate, controltemplates

I am new here and hope my first question meets stack overflow's requirements. I have done some research so far but could not figure it out myself. 
I create a UserControl (derived from an intermediate base Class) which should be able to change a color sign to a different color depending on its "VisualAlarmState" Property which is a DependencyProperty.
The Style plus ControlTemplate are rendered as expected but the DataTrigger at the end of the style does not change the color (=image) of VisualAlarmSign which is an Image element.
The code can be compiled and run without errors but the alarm state will not be shown as expected.
Something I do ot really understand either: I have to reference the Style dynamically because Style="{StaticResource DashboardItemStyle}" will be underlinded and at mouse hover says: "The resource "DashboardItemStyle" could not be resolved."

```
<ucbase:DashboardItemBase.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="MO-Zylinderdeckel" UriSource="/ModuleDashboard;component/Resources/MO-Zylinderdeckel.tif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="MO-Zylindermantel" UriSource="/ModuleDashboard;component/Resources/MO-Zylindermantel.tif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="MO-Zylinderboden" UriSource="/ModuleDashboard;component/Resources/MO-Zylinderboden.tif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="MO-Marker-Grün" UriSource="/ModuleDashboard;component/Resources/MO-Marker-Grün.tif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="MO-Marker-Orange" UriSource="/ModuleDashboard;component/Resources/MO-Marker-Orange.tif" />
            <BitmapImage x:Key="MO-Marker-Rot" UriSource="/ModuleDashboard;component/Resources/MO-Marker-Rot.tif" />

    <Style x:Key="DashboardItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ucbase:DashboardItemBase}">

        <Setter Property="Template" x:Name="Template1">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ucbase:DashboardItemBase}">                        
                    <dxlc:Tile x:Name="Tile" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                            Height="128.5" Width="208.5" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <dxlc:Tile.Content>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="11.5" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="12.5" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6.5" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Source="{StaticResource MO-Zylinderdeckel}" />

                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6.5" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Source="{StaticResource MO-Zylindermantel}" />


                                        <Image x:Name="VisualAlarmSign" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="14"
                                            Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="19.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{StaticResource MO-Marker-Grün}" />
                                </Grid>

                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Source="{StaticResource MO-Zylinderboden}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </dxlc:Tile.Content>
                    </dxlc:Tile>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <!-- This Trigger has no effect. Why?-->
                        <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=VisualAlarmState}">
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <vmbase:AlarmState>Alarm</vmbase:AlarmState>
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <Setter TargetName="VisualAlarmSign" Property="Source"
                                    Value="{StaticResource MO-Marker-Rot}" />
                        </DataTrigger>                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ucbase:DashboardItemBase.Resources>
```

**Working Solution**

I removed `Source={StaticResource MO-Marker-Grün}` from the `<Image>` element and I moved the `<DataTrigger>` from `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` to  `<Style.Triggers>` in `<Image.Style>` which resulted in the following XAML code:

```
<ucbase:DashboardItemBase.Resources>
    ...
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MO-Marker-Rot" UriSource="/ModuleDashboard;component/Resources/MO-Marker-Rot.tif" />
    ...
        <Style x:Key="DashboardItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ucbase:DashboardItemBase}">
            <Setter Property="Template" x:Name="Template1">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ucbase:DashboardItemBase}">                        
                        <dxlc:Tile x:Name="Tile" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                Height="128.5" Width="208.5" Background="{x:Null}">
                            <dxlc:Tile.Content>
                                <Grid>
                                    ...                                     
                                    <Image x:Name="VisualAlarmSign" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"
                                            Height="14" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="19.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                                        <Image.Style>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger
                                                            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=VisualAlarmState}"
                                                            Value="Alarm">
                                                        <Setter Property="Image.Source"
                                                                Value="{StaticResource MO-Marker-Rot}" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Image.Style>
                                    </Image>
                                    ...
                                </Grid>
                            </dxlc:Tile.Content>                        
                        </dxlc:Tile>                        
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</ucbase:DashboardItemBase.Resources>
```

Comment: Code looks fine.
Check if you have binding errors in your Output ToolWindow. Have you tried binding the alarmstate to an ordinary textblock, just to make sure the binding to the DP is working properly?

Comment: By the way, if AlarmState is enum, you may simply use Value="Alarm" in a Trigger without specifying type.

Comment: @ Marat Khasanov: Thanks for this advice<br/>@SvenG: VisualAlarmState works perfect with binding to a Label.Content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the source of image using style property setter. Some how trigger behave wired.

```
<Image x:Name="VisualAlarmSign" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="14"
                                            Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="19.5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image.Style>
    <Style>
     <Setter TargetName="VisualAlarmSign" Property="Source"
                                        Value="{StaticResource MO-Marker-Grün}" />
    </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Make sure to remove the source property in the image tag.

Some how triggers may not set properties we have used in the tag. in your case you set the value of source in the image tag. if you set the same value through style setter it may worm. its worth a try.

Comment: Using Image.Style does not work, because I get a compile-time error: "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter."

Comment: remove target name in the setter.. we don't need targetname in setter because we are setting the style for same object.. you may need to use Property="Image.Source" in the place of Property="Source"

Comment: Thanks, the exception is gone now, but the trigger still has no effect.

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted because finally your solution worked more or less: I moved the DataTriggers from the <ControlTemplate.Triggers> to the <Style.Triggers> within <Image.Style>. The only drawback I get is that I only see the alarm states at runtime and not at design time - any suggestions why and possibillities to solve that? - By the way, you where right that I also had to remove the source property in the image tag to make it work.